# Given a graph generated by Delaunay triangulation, how can I evenly distribute colors to each node?

Tags: graph-theory, delaunay, voronoi, procedural-generation, graph-coloring

Part of the procedural generation algorithm for the map of a game I'm developing requires event data to be distributed among the nodes of the map (Voronoi regions, generated by the delaunay graph). Most of the nodes have "combat" events, but I need to distribute "town" events roughly evenly so the player can shop, heal, etc. If I randomly distribute the "town" events, I could run into clumping issues.

My Graph Theory fu is kind of weak, but this is the clearest wording I could work up:

Given some graph G constructed from the Delaunay triangulation, with all nodes colored some color c0, how can I evenly distribute another color c1 (at some frequency/density) so that i avoid "clumps" of c1 as much as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use weighted delaunay triangulation. Then swap the points with the center of mass of the polygon. Rinse and repeat.